# Plato's Republic education system

Tags: plato, education, the-republic

What is the education system that Plato proposed?

E.g. the United States education system might be:

- 3-4 basic counting and communication
- 5-6 basic math, reading, writing, shapes, and time
- 7-11 deeper exploration of the above holistic curriculum, and science, technology, social studies
- 12-18 more advanced math, algebra, geometry, language and literacy
- 18-22 optional becoming an expert in one subject
- 22-24 optional catching up to limit of human knowledge of one subject
- 24-30 optional expanding the limit of human knowledge in one area

What does Plato's outline look like and why?

Comment: Just to be clear about the scope of the question -- *The Republic* by Plato is a philosophical dialogue with a bunch of characters making arguments, often contrary arguments for positions in disagreement with each other. Plato portrays another person, *Socrates*, as arguing at great length about education (in the course of making an argument about the nature of justice). Are you asking about what Socrates is depicted as saying about education in the Republic? Or about what we might glean about Plato's own views on education from the arguments he depicts Socrates as making? Or something else?

Comment: (I ask 1. because the relationship between the arguments that Plato's own philosophical views and the arguments he depicts Socrates as making in *The Republic*, is itself a matter of debate; and 2. if you are asking not narrowly about the text, but more broadly about Plato's own considered views, there are some other forms of evidence that might be relevant to consider, since Plato himself founded and managed an educational institution, wrote other dialogues, etc.; but these won't be very relevant in any direct way if the question is mainly a question about the text of *The Republic*.

Comment: @AlabamaScholiast I was thinking about what Socrates describes when I asked the question, and hope an answer can explicitly lay out this (what is described in The Republic), But I would be very interested to hear what Plato himself might actually believe

Comment: Sounds good; could I suggest that you edit the question a bit to more explicitly state that the textual question is your main object here? E.g. instead of asking "What does Plato's outline look like," something more like *Does this/how does this differ from what Plato's Socrates outlines in the Republic?* or similar?

Comment: It wouldn't be an Answer to this question, but my education system would include spending the entire summer break from school on a remote island in a small cabin in the woods with no TV, no computer, no telephone, running water, heating, cooling, roads and few other people. It worked for me, 50 years ago. Got a lot of reading done.

Answer (score 1):

Plato proposed a mass education system in the Republic and not one solely for the sons of the aristocracy. To understand the success of this idea one only need note just how many countries have such a system. In fact, out of the 195 countries in the world, there are only five that do not have a compulsory mass education system: Bhutan, Oman, Papua New Guinea, Solomon Islands and Vatican City.

His educational system underpinned his recommended political system - a republic. Although he is popularly thought to think democracy a bad form of politics, he in fact denounced the bad form of democracy, populism. He thought that for democracy and hence his republic to work, education was key.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit of stretch to say that Plato's Republic-(and Plato in general), established (or even popularized), the concept or policy of a mass educational system-(similar to what exists in much of the world today). Plato's Academy, was very much, a clubby, members only type of institution with its famed inscription-("Only Mathematicians can enter"...I am paraphrasing the statement and I apologize for its inexactness). Plato's Academy was an educational institution, but it also functioned as a fraternal organization, a type of intellectual brotherhood-(as one of the Commentators stated). The design and purpose of Plato's Academy was actually, the opposite of a mass educational system.

It is difficult to find examples of a mass educational system in the Ancient world, with the possible exception of Alexandria, Egypt during its Hellenistic and Roman heydays. Ancient Alexandria was home to the world's largest and most cosmopolitan Library, though it was also home to the world's 1st College/University-(which is lesser known). But, even the Alexandrian Library/College was still, quite elitist and only available to the (more well-to-do) citizens of The Ptolemaic and later Roman Empires.

Comparatively speaking, the Alexandrian Library/College would have been viewed as a Proletariat's Paradise by Plato and the first generation of Academy students.

Comment: There's a difference between Plato's Academy and what he himself advocated. It's well known that democracy in the Western world is traced back to the Athenian polity during Pericles time. Nevertheless, their democracy would not be recognised as a democracy today with the franchise being restricted to men of property. Likewise with education.

Comment: Actually, there is little difference between Plato, the School Headmaster/Teacher and Plato, the Philosophical Author as it relates to Education and Society.  By today's standards, Plato, would be viewed as an Elitist's Elitist and definitely not a champion of the Proletariat.  And even during his lifetime, Plato, was no fan of Democracy or a Universally educated society.  One could make the case that Plato's most learned student, Aristotle MAY have supported a more democratized society/polity, though that would be a bit of stretch as well.

Comment: It's an error to judge a man by the standards of our time. There was no such thing as a proletariat at that time - there was no industrialising commodities then. Plato championed the people against the oligarchy in Athens and in his philosophy, wrote against tyranny - that makes him a man of the people.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that Plato-(the historical figure), was definitely NOT..."a man of the people".   Plato. the son of a wealthy Athenian Ship Owner, who, in his younger years, traveled 'far and wide" and in his later years, founded The  Academy-(an educational institution primarily geared for the wealthiest and brightest of Athenian male citizens), was not exactly a righteous populist.

Comment: You aren't demonstrating any knowledge or understanding *The Republic*, but you do show a remarkably limited knowledge of Plato's life. That someone comes from a wealthy aristocratic family is no barrier to being a man of the people. After all, the late Tony Benn was the Viscount Stansgate and was educated at Oxford but he was also a trotskyist - another real man of the people.

Comment: Well, if you read my above comment, in its entirety, you will notice that I was trying to make the larger point that Plato, (the little historical information that is available to us), was far from being "a man of the people".  I don't think you really understand Plato's historical biography or philosophical writings if you keep insisting that he was "a man of the people"...he was the furthest thing from it.  Just because Plato opposed Tyranny, did not automatically qualify him as a "man of the people".  Your Trotskyite example, is-(as I said before), "a bit of a stretch."

Comment: You haven't mentioned anything at all from *The Republic* in either your answer or your comments. All you have to go on is his biography and apocrypha that 'only mathematicians are allowed to enter' which is also quoted wrong. It's unlikely this was placed over Plato's Academy. You seem to think that anyone from a wealthy background cannot be a man of the people. I pointed out Tony Benn as a contemporary example where this is simply untrue. And no, you did not say that was 'a bit of a stretch'. You're even misquoting yourself wrongly so how are we to trust you when quoting from ...

Comment: ... texts? Not that you are quoting, but the point still stands.

Comment: Well, for the record, the information that I stated was not apocryphal.  As for my quotations, you may want to reexamine them more carefully and more contextually.  The Trotskyite example you give, is meaningless and has absolutely no relevance in this discussion.  However, the larger point is as follows; Plato, both the man and the author, was NEVER, "a man of the people"-(even by contemporary standards).  And If you continue to restate and insist upon such ahistorical nonsense, then there's not much more I can say.  My position remains unchanged.

Comment: You're the one who should be checking your references. If you do so, you will find that there was no sign above the Plato's Academy saying "Only mathematicians can enter ...". Can you provide a reference for that - a serious one?

Comment: As I said before, my position remains unchanged.

Comment: Whether or not you're correct about Plato's own views or class affiliations, @Alex, this isn't a very good answer to the question that was asked, because the question that was asked is a question about the arguments made in a specific text (*The Republic* by Plato; I suspected & have since confirmed in a comment thread above, that it is more specifically a question about the arguments advanced by the character of Socrates in that dialogue). That question about the text is best answered by mentioning or at least alluding to passages in the text of *The Republic*, which you haven't done.

Comment: Admittedly, my answer was actually in direct response to Mozibur's opening sentence..."Plato proposed a mass education system in The Republic and not one solely for the sons of the aristocracy."  My objection was more towards his premise and opening sentence and yes, my comment/answer did not fully answer the original question....(my apologies).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you imply expecting a prescriptive list of tasks by age. Education was far less formalised and systematic in his era, with children of the elite often having their own tutors able to tailor educational programmes. In fact he says:

> "Where would be the use of going into further details about the dances
> of our citizens, or about their hunting and coursing, their gymnastic
> and equestrian contests? For these all follow the general principle,
> and having found that, we shall have no difficulty in discovering
> them."

He is occupied in the text with the purpose of education, *for the state*, not the details of it. Plato believed that education should be state controlled, and that everyone in the state must have access to free and quality education. But for him that didn't mean rote memorising. The difference in his views to modern assumptions and likely those of many in his time, is crystallised when he says:

> "Bodily exercise, when compulsory, does no harm to the body; but
> knowledge which is acquired under compulsion obtains no hold on the
> mind."

And he says of the purpose of education:

> "That's what education should be," I said, "the art of orientation.
> Educators should devise the simplest and most effective methods of
> turning minds around. It shouldn't be the art of implanting sight in
> the organ, but should proceed on the understanding that the organ
> already has the capacity, but is improperly aligned and isn't facing
> the right way."

He was also a fan of censoring any stories he disapproved of:

> "Then the first thing will be to establish a censorship of the writers
> of fiction, and let the censors receive any tale of fiction which is
> good, and reject the bad; and we will desire mothers and nurses to
> tell their children the authorised ones only"

Which he extends into [condemning poetry in general](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/articles/69373/from-the-republic), and exiling poets from The Republic, for imitating things in a way that distorts, corrupting youth, and inciting the passions.

In contrast:

> "musical training is a more potent instrument than any other, because
> rhythm and harmony find their way into the inward places of the soul,
> on which they mightily fasten, imparting grace, and making the soul of
> him who is rightly educated graceful, or of him who is ill-educated
> ungraceful; and also because he who has received this true education
> of the inner being will most shrewdly perceive omissions or faults in
> art and nature, and with a true taste, while he praises and rejoices
> over and receives into his soul the good, and becomes noble and good,
> he will justly blame and hate the bad, now in the days of his youth,
> even before he is able to know the reason why; and when reason comes
> he will recognise and salute the friend with whom his education has
> made him long familiar."

He was similarly positive about gymnastic training of the body, but again that would be towards serving the state, like in war.

On gender equality he strikes a remarkably progressive tone:

> "The education which was assigned to the men was music and gymnastic.
> Yes.
>
> Then women must be taught music and gymnastic and also the art of war,
> which they must practise like the men?
>
> That is the inference, I suppose."

On when to study philosophy he says:

> "In childhood and youth their study, and what philosophy they learn,
> should be suited to their tender years: during this period while they
> are growing up towards manhood, the chief and special care should be
> given to their bodies that they may have them to use in the service of
> philosophy; as life advances and the intellect begins to mature, let
> them increase the gymnastics of the soul; but when the strength of our
> citizens fails and is past civil and military duties, then let them
> range at will and engage in no serious labour, as we intend them to
> live happily here, and to crown this life with a similar happiness in
> another."

He compares the philosopher to the navigator of a ship who should have charge of it's course through special training and insight. Only the philosopher navigates by knowledge of the Good, of virtues, and of justice which is about knowing balance and harmony. He is clear studying philosophy is not for everyone, but only those of highly good character who will not be bad soil for it.

Comment: Comprehensive. We can see why all the rest of Philosophy is called "footnotes to Plato". These days, I think that we will not long survive without some pretty aggressive censorship of media that is not only unuseful but actually destructive.

Comment: @ScottRowe: Plato was a fascist. If you look at the problems that arose with the printing press, the solution was at least as much more education, as it was censorship.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I wasn't endorsing fascism or censorship per se, but you might have to censor a firehose if you are drowning before you get enough education to cope with it.  I am thinking lately that the complexity of the world has grown entirely beyond human capability to manage. I might ask a Question to that effect.

Comment: @ScottRowe: Sounds interesting. Our world now, is so vastly more complex than that of those caught up by the pamphleteering that triggered the witch-panics. What does it mean to 'cope' with complexity? Were they coping? When did we stop? Our cosmos, & especially biology, have always been vastly more complex than we can understand, & things like mycelial life & bacterial biofilms are still barely understood, & vastly consequential. We are children loose in a garden that took 4 billion years to build. Computers have minimal complexity by comparison

Comment: I am sure you're right, the universe is big and old. But I see people struggling with relatively new problems that seemed more manageable before. Banking comes to mind. And that is worsened by how easy it is to spend money now. Ordering online can bring you dinner, products, games, movies... People can easily spend all their income without even noticing. They can spend all their time and focus too. "*I'm so broke, I can't even* pay attention."

Comment: @ScottRowe: https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/booked I think we need some kind of balance: willed optimism to support cooperation, while preparing for the worst.

Comment: We should really learn to trust the right people.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144891/discussion-between-criglcragl-and-scott-rowe).

Comment: @ScottRowe: Philosopher Kings, amiright...? Lol. Game theory suggests all trust should have limits. God-emperors have always done terrible things.